# How should I think of schemes of the form $\operatorname{spec} k[f_1, \ldots, f_n]$, $f_i \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_m]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, schemes

How should I think of schemes of the form $\operatorname{spec} k[f_1, \ldots, f_n]$, $f_i \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_m]$? What of the map on spectra induced by the inclusion $i : k[f_1, \ldots, f_n] \to k[x_1, \ldots, x_m]$? What are the processes that construct these kinds of spectra?

What I am looking for: a reasonable answer to thinking of schemes of the form $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n] / I$ is as closed subschemes, varieties in $k^n$, etc.... is there an analogous familiar object for the spectra of subrings?

I know (vaguely) that sometimes these are quotients by group actions (the ring of invariants). I also know (vaguely) that sometimes they are obtained by gluing along closed subschemes. Are there other process that can construct schemes like these? There seems to be a common theme here, for instance we are taking $A^n$ and pinching, twisting, covering it onto itself - except that I think the dimension can go up, weirdly, as in $k[x,xy,xy^2,\ldots]$.)

Can this be made more precise?

Comment: The corresponding maps of affine schemes are precisely the epimorphisms out of affine space. In that sense they loosely behave like quotients. But the quotient intuition should really be reserved for regular epimorphisms, and probably these epimorphisms aren't all regular. In general epimorphisms that aren't regular are poorly behaved and usually the wrong thing to look at.